# How can I use regular expressions in my vocabulary for CountVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, text-classification, countvectorizer

How do I make "First word in the doc was [target word]" a feature?

Consider these two sentences:

```
example = ["At the moment, my girlfriend is Jenny. She is working as an artist at the moment.",
       "My girlfriend is Susie. She is working as an accountant at the moment."]
```

If I were trying to measure relationship commitment, I'd want to be able to treat the phrase "at the moment" as a feature *only* when it shows up at the beginning like that.

I would *love* to be able to use regex's in the vocabulary...

```
phrases = ["^at the moment", 'work']
vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=phrases, ngram_range=(1, 3), token_pattern=r'\w{1,}')
dtm = vect.fit_transform(example)
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

I have also tried this, but get a 'vocabulary is empty' error...

```
CountVectorizer(token_pattern = r"(?u)^currently")
```

What's the right way to do this? Do I need a custom vectorizer? Any simple tutorials you can link me to? This is my first sklearn project, and I've been Googling this for hours. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I've figured out a way, based on hacking the get_tweet_length() function in this tutorial...
https://ryan-cranfill.github.io/sentiment-pipeline-sklearn-4/

I added this function...

```
def first_words(text):
    matchesList = re.findall('^at the moment', text, re.I)
    if len(matchesList) > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

And used them with base sklearn_helper `pipelinize_feature()` function, which converts output into the array format desired by the sklearn's FeautreUnion function.

```
vect4 = pipelinize_feature(first_words, active=True)
```

I can then use this along with my normal CountVectorizers via FeatureUnion

```
unionObj = FeatureUnion([
        ('vect1', vect1),
        ('vect2', vect2),
        ('vect4', vect4)
])
```